# Hiding qemu virtualization in guest Windows 10

Tags: virtualization, qemu

I know this will probably be a bit of a repeat but none of the several topics I have browsed and tried have worked out fully for me. I will try to give as much (necessary) info as I can, if there is unrelated info or info that is needed please tell me what and how I can retrieve it and I'll do my best. Sorry it's long I just wanna be thorough with my question and info.

Thank you for taking your time to read this.

#### Main Issue

I am trying to hide the fact that it's a VM from my guest, mainly because I want to play some games that do not play well with their anti-cheat being on a VM, for example Valorant. I have tried many guides online but none seem to work. While windows thinks it's running on outside a virtual machine, Checking in PAFish these are the traces I get.

#### PAFish Traces

```
[-] CPU information based detections
[*] Checking the difference between CPU timestamp counters (rdtsc) forcing VM exit ... traced!
[*] Checking hypervisor bit in cpuid feature bits ... traced!            
[*] Checking cpuid hypervisor vendor for known VM vendors ... traced!             

[-] Generic sandbox detection 
[*] Using mouse activity ... traced!                   
[*] Checking operating system uptime using GetTickCount() ... traced!

[-] Qemu detection
[*] Scsi port->bus->target id->logical unit id-> 0 identifier ... traced!

[-] Bochs detection
[*] Reg key (HKLM\HARDWARE\Description\System "SystemBiosVersion") ... traced!
```

And I want to try to fix/mitigate them. Now I realize that Valorant AC might use some other ways as well but I figure this is a good place to start.

Below will be a bit of an infodump of what I have done attempting this.

**My cpu, motherboard and OS are:**

```
OS: Manjaro Linux x86_64
Host: MS-7C37 2.0
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3800X (16) @ 3.900GHz
```

*I have enabled nested virtualization for my AMD CPU*

I am running qemu under virt-manager with windows 10 Pro 64bit as a guest. [Here](https://pastebin.com/0y0MTWiG) is a pastebin of my xml file for my VM but I will include what I think are the relevant parts for each trace in each section.

#### SystemBiosVersion

**The more important (I think) parts are that I have changed the bios vendor etc:**

```
<sysinfo type="smbios">
<bios>
  <entry name="vendor">American Megatrends Inc.</entry>
  <entry name="version">A.40</entry>
  <entry name="date">09/10/2019</entry>
</bios>
<system>
  <entry name="manufacturer">Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.</entry>
  <entry name="product">MS-7C37</entry>
  <entry name="version">2.0</entry>
  <entry name="serial">SOME RANDOM STRING OF CHARS HERE</entry>
  <entry name="uuid">MY UUID IS HERE</entry>
  <entry name="sku">SOME RANDOM STRING OF CHARS HERE</entry> //Don't even know what should be here
  <entry name="family">MSI Gaming</entry>
</system>
```

But it still traces SystemBiosVersion, this I can change through a registry edit but I don't know if that would help since it needs to be changed every system reboot.

#### CPU Information Based Detections

**My CPU and Hyper-V settings are as follows:**

```
<features>
  <acpi/>
  <apic/>
  <hyperv>
    <relaxed state="on"/>
    <vapic state="on"/>
    <spinlocks state="on" retries="8191"/>
    <vendor_id state="on" value="SOME RANDOM STRING OF CHARS HERE"/>
  </hyperv>
  <kvm>
    <hidden state="on"/>
  </kvm>
  <vmport state="off"/>
</features>
<cpu mode="host-passthrough" check="none" migratable="on">
  <topology sockets="1" dies="1" cores="8" threads="2"/>
  <cache level="3" mode="emulate"/>
  <feature policy="disable" name="hypervisor"/>
  <feature policy="require" name="svm"/>
  <feature policy="require" name="invtsc"/>
  <feature policy="require" name="topoext"/>
</cpu>
<clock offset="localtime">
  <timer name="rtc" tickpolicy="catchup"/>
  <timer name="hpet" present="no"/>
  <timer name="hypervclock" present="yes"/>
  <timer name="pit" tickpolicy="discard"/>
</clock>
```

From what I've read the "*feature disable hypervisor*" part should fix the 2 latter CPU traces but that might've been me misunderstanding what they do.

#### Qemu detection

Here I use:

```
<disk type="file" device="disk">
  <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2"/>
  <source file="/run/media/jd/Windows/win10.qcow2"/>
  <target dev="sda" bus="sata"/>
  <serial>SOME RANDOM-ISH TEXT</serial>
  <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="0"/>
</disk>
<disk type="file" device="disk">
  <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2"/>
  <source file="/run/media/jd/3TB/VM/WindowsHDD.qcow2"/>
  <target dev="sdc" bus="sata"/>
  <serial>SOME RANDOM-ISH TEXT</serial>
  <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="1"/>
</disk>
```

But it still traces it from some logical unit id identifier, I found this in the registry where it still said QEMU HARDDRIVE, I changed that string and it was no longer traced but like the SystemBiosVersion this isn't a permanent solution and I don't know if it even helps.

In my device and task manager both drives are named QEMU HARDDRIVE but I haven't found a way to change those names without recompiling qemu with a change in it's source code.. Well Actually I found ways to change it if you used scsi drives, but those aren't detected. And I also found some changelog entry referencing "model=m" to change the names but I haven't found where to put that and no-one else referencing that other than mirrors of that changelog.

#### Generic sandbox detection

As for these I don't really even know where to start, I haven't tried to hide them. I use Barrier / Synergy to share my mouse and keyboard so I suspect that's the mouse activity trace but I don't feel like that would trigger VAC.

#### Final words

And that is all I have to give you. I hope I've formulated my question properly and given the needed information, again please tell me if it's too much, wrong or just stupid. I don't have much if any deep knowledge of qemu at all and this has been done mainly following found guides online which I've then put together onto this test-vm. Thank you for taking your time to read at least some of this and thank you further if you try to help me :)

Comment: QEMU is not designed to be hidden. You do not have any chance to make this work, sorry. But maybe check [this fork of QEMU](https://github.com/SoftwareGuy/stealthChamp-qemu) that was made for this exact purpose. It may not be suitable for games.

Answer (score 1):

I recalled watching a [guide to this on Jim Browning's youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TM45vNI4Qc)

I know that this is slightly different from your setup, since it's vmware specific, but there is a good walkthrough of the things to be aware of, such as the name of the harddisk controllers, whicih is an obvious giveaway. I hope this helps out a bit.

### From the video description:

> You'll need the following Registry Point:
>
> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum
> ```
>
> Search for the following 4 GUIDs:
>
> ```
> {4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
> {4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
> {4d36e965-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
> {4d36e96f-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
> ```
>
> You can download the VMware Tools stealthy registry files from [links in youtube link]
>
> This will work for Windows 7, 8, 8.1 and 10 with VMware tools 10.10

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at this.

Comment: How to apply that on Qemu KVM virtulization? I got NextParentID keys names?

Comment: Have you looked at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum` entries? there might be one that fits with the one you need to change